# How to add the locale to the account page in Keycloak?

Tags: themes, keycloak

We need to let our users to set the preferred locale.
I can see that the locale is editable by a select menu in the users' admin page but it is not present in the default theme account page.
In our custom theme we want to add the select menu for the locale, is there a standard way?

In the API UserRepresentation doesn't have a locale property, do we need to use an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved adding this element in the `account.ftl` template of the account theme, just after the `lastName` div

```html
        <div class="form-group ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('locale','has-error')}">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <label for="user.attributes.locale" class="control-label">${msg("locale")}</label> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="user.attributes.locale" name="user.attributes.locale">
                    <#list locale.supported as l>
                        <option class="kc-dropdown-item" <#if l.languageTag==account.attributes.locale!'en'>selected="selected"</#if> value="${l.languageTag}">${l.label}</option>
                    </#list>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

We need also to add the `locale` label to `messages_xx.properties` files for the supported locales